# Find the root node of a binary tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

This was one of the questions asked in a interview. Where I need to find the root node of the binary tree. There is no parent node like (Node parent) in the below definition of binary tree.

We have access to any node in the binary tree. It can be root or it can be any other node as well.

Binary tree :

```
                1
              /   \
             2     3
            / \   / \
           4   5 6   7
```

We might have access to say Node 5

Definition of Binary Tree is as below :

```
class Node
{
   int data;
   Node left;
   Node right;
   Node(int data)
   {
     this.data = data;
     this.left = null;
     this.right = null;
   }
 }
```

Any ideas how I can be achieved this.

```
public Node getParent(Node current)
{

}
```

Thanks !

Comment: you just asked one question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488113/balanced-bracket-questions. You should have tried it yourself. What have you tried when you came back??

Comment: Please stop dumping your interview questions on this site, without demonstrating some effort of your own.

Comment: If you have access to any node in the tree, you could make a traverse for every node, and see from what node you get the most children. That will run in ``O(n^2)``

Comment: Interesting. I don't see how it's possible if you only have access to node 5 (and from there its children) and no other nodes. If you have access to all nodes, in for example a List<Node>, you could look up its parent in there, and eventually find the root node. (but a bit slow)

Comment: 1) You're saying that you "have access to any node". In the signature of `getParent`, only a single node is available. How does this fit together? Were you supposed to work with JVM debugging interfaces? 2) Are you sure that that was the question? It doesn't seem to have any O(1) answers. The best thing you could do would be to to iterate over all nodes, or to build another tree structure which saves pointers to `parent`.

Comment: Again, this is a question-and-answer site, not a coding-interview repository.  You are going to learn absolutely nothing by looking at our answers to such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there may be many roots in the graph, that is node without parents or simply not reference by another node.

You could go through all node 1 time, and put the child node you encounter into a Set. The roots (node without parents) is the difference between all nodes in the tree and nodes in the set.

This would work in O(N), N being the number of nodes as long as the equals/hashCode method are fast. If the node are not duplicated in memory you would be able the memory reference for equality/hashCode and be extremely fast.

But this is only one random solution. You may want to change the data structure for example to have on one side all the nodes and on the other side a pointer to the root so then the access become O(1).

You should check a book on algorithmics to see all the possible solutions that make sense with their benefits and drawbacks.

Hopefully for an interview, what the interviewer look for is not necessarily that you know the response but that you are able to understand the problem, ask question to be sure you got it right, find at least one solution even if naive, be able to criticize it and potentially know way of improving it (like reading the book on algorithms).

Comment: 1)  The question states it is a tree (not a graph); so there is one root.  2)  Rather than starting with a blank set, I would suggest first populating the Set with all nodes, and removing nodes that are children.  In this way, the remaining node in the set is the root.

Comment: Overall this is quite similar... both code iterated twice and both go through the data overall twice. The hypothesis that is a single root is simply not necessary. In all case we find all roots, be it there one or one hundred ;)